# Remove whitespace before & after float element

Tags: html, css, whitespace

Float elements are supposed to stay together side by side (as column). But, if we have to push some float elements below other float elements, it'll create some whitespace. I am talking about this structure where it can be happened:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
   <div class="col"></div>
   <div class="col"></div>
   <div class="col"></div>
   <div class="col"></div>
   <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Considering CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
   .col { 
      width: 50%;
 }
```

}

At that scenario, this will be happened (< 992px screen):

[image]

I don't want that extra gap. I want this:

[image]

How to **remove the extra space without changing the structure of HTML**?

[**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/nhj1x1br/2/)

Answer (score 0):

as i try on the fiddle its because of the percentage % you added to width 50% 
you can switch it to static number of pixels if that will work with the requirements .

i just switch

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
   .col { 
      width: 50%;
 }
```

with

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  }
```

[Find Edit Here](https://jsfiddle.net/javamn2000/7xxc1u6L/)

Comment: Fixed width is not possible as it's responsive. Fixed height is not possible as the contents are dynamic.

Comment: i think you must make one of them static and the other dynamic i didn't now if there are some solution to make the both working dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You could use this JQuery code on page load and window resize:

```
$('.col').each(function(i, el) {

  if (i % 2 === 0) {

    if ( $(el).height() > $(el).next().height() ) {

      $(el).next().height( $(el).height() );

    } else {

      $(el).height($(el).next().height());

    }

  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fabio1983/nhj1x1br/3/

Comment: Actually, I don't want equal height, I want there will be no extra space; something like this: http://i.imgur.com/eQzEJH4.png